# Can't use the set function on Typescript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, set, apache-arrow

I want to use the set function to turn only the unique values of an array into a separate array. This is my code:

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { Table } from 'apache-arrow';

const arrow = readFileSync('file.arrow');
const table = Table.from(arrow);
const table_array = table.toArray();
var values : string[] = [];

for(let i = 0; i < table_array.length; ++i){
    var str = table_array[i][1]
    var id_val = str.toString().split('.');
    values.push(id_val[6]);
}

var unique_id = [...new Set(values)];

console.log(values)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
error TS2569: Type 'Set<string>' is not an array type or a string type.
var unique_id = [...new Set(values)];
```

This is the console output. I had to hide the values but they are numbers in string format:

```
[
  '####', '####', '####', '####', '####',
  '####', '####', '####', '####', '####',
  '####', '####', '####', '####', '####',
  '####', '####', '####', '####', '####',
  ... 427 more items
]
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Check the edits

Comment: How would I give it a type?

Comment: That wasn't the point, the point was just that since there's no type on the variable, TypeScript will be able to infer its type without any constraints that might otherwise make it give you an error. (If you're assigning to a variable at the point you declare it, it's often best practice to let TypeScript infer the type, as you have with `unique_id` -- though that should be `let` or `const`, not `var`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set this `downlevelIteration` property to your `tsconfig.json` file to allow iterating of iterables as suggested by the editor

```
{

"compilerOptions": {
       ...

      "downlevelIteration": true
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: A better option would be to upgrade the target to es6 if possible.